# Why is index.bindClient is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Why is this not a function? Importing `./src/index.js` in `./index.js` works just fine, but trying to import it in `./src/Client.js` just doesn't let me. It's not some "invalid file path" because I don't have any errors, and it autofilled in the `require` function.

Here is my code:

`./index.js`

```js
const index = require("./src/index.js")
console.log(index) //logs the module
```

`./src/Client.js`

```js
const index = require("./index.js") //I even tried require("../src/index.js") and the full path (D:/...)
console.log(index) //logs empty object

index.bindClient(client) //TypeError: index.bindClient is not a function
```

`./src/index.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    Send,
    MessageDelete,
    Command,
    Client: C,
/**
 * 
 * @param {Client} client
 */
    bindClient(client) {
        c = client;
        return (
            c.on("messageCreate", msg => {
            const command = commands.find(c => msg.content.startsWith(c.name))
            if (command) {
                command.send ? Send(command.send, msg.channel) : null
                command.delete ? MessageDelete(msg) : null
                command.emit("execute", msg, command)
            }
        })
        );
    }
}
```

This is not my full code, I only included the important parts that relate to the error. I tried logging as much as I could and everything except for `index` in `./src/Client.js` was what it was supposed to be. This error even happened when I tried to set it like `module.exports.bindClient = ...`

Comment: Do you have a cyclic depending module occuring? E.g: A requires B, B requires C, C|B requires A

Comment: Oh yeah, `./src/index.js` requires `./src/Client.js` and `./src/Client.js` requires `./src/index.js`

Comment: That may be the issue, it's possible for exports in cyclic depencancies to come up empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by [@Elitezen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12464931/elitezen) in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69839747/why-is-index-bindclient-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment123454835_69839747), the files were requiring each other. Putting the `require` at the bottom and calling the function directly from it worked

```js
require("./index.js").bindClient(client)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure it...

```
const { Send, MessageDelete, Command, Client, bindClient } = require("./src/index.js")
```

Comment: I tried this before. It still said `bindClient` is not a function